# Problema con selector dinamico undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, laravel

Hola tengo un problema con mi selector dinamico, me funciona de manera correcta, excepto que no me muestra los valores en el segundo select, creo que el problema esta en el codigo java script al imprimir el valor en cada select ya que me itera de forma correcta el numero de  semestres pero no muestra su valor

Codigo Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('#select-carrera').on('change', onselectcarrerachange);
});

function onselectcarrerachange() {

    var pensum_id = $(this).val();


    if (!pensum_id) {
        $('#select-semestre').html('<option value "">Seleccione un semestre</option>') return
    }

    $.get('/api/nueva-seccion/' + pensum_id + '/semestres', function(data) {

        var html_select = '<option value "">Seleccione un semestre</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) html_select += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        $('#select-semestre').html(html_select);
    });
}
```

Html selectores

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
     <div class="input-group"   title="Carrera">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>


    <select  class="form-control"   id="select-carrera">

    <option  value="">Seleccione carrerra    </option>
    @foreach ($pensum as $n)
    <option  value="{{$n->id}} "> {{$n->carrera}} | Regimen: {{$n->regimen}} |  Vigencia: {{$n->vigencia}}  </option>

    @endforeach

    </select>


    </div>
    </div>




<div class="form-group col-sm-8">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"  title="Semestre" ><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>



  <select  class="form-control"   id="select-semestre">
<option  value="">Semestres</option>

</select>



</div> 
</div>
```

Capture de mi consola  con un console.log(data);

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

**Console.log antes del for**

```
console.log(data);
var html_select='<option value "">Seleccione un semestre</option>';
for ( var i =0 ; i<data.length; ++i) 
    html_select +='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
$('#select-semestre').html(html_select);
});
```

Resultado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has un `console.log(data)` en el request y dinos que muestra la consola

Comment: listo amigo, ya puedes verla

Comment: Pusiste el `console.log` antes del `for`?

Comment: lo puse despues ya subo de nuevo

Comment: Ponlo exactamente antes del for y publica el resultado.

Comment: listo resultado publicado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta de tu json no tiene un apropiedad `name` definida por lo que hace undefined.

La respueta solo tiene definida las siguientes propiedades:

```
{
 id: Number,
 semestre: String,
 penum_id: Number,
 created_at: String,
 updated_at: String
}
```

Tienes que agregar la propiedad `name` a tu respuesta en el servidor para lograr que funcione.

Actualizacion:

Si quieres imprimir el campo semestre, entonces cambia `data[i].name` por `data[i].semestre`:

```
var html_select='<option value "">Seleccione un semestre</option>';
for ( var i =0 ; i<data.length; ++i) 
    html_select +='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].semestre+'</option>';
     $('#select-semestre').html(html_select);
});
```

Comment: quiero imprimir el campo semestre

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada.